# Is there any way to change Eclipse editor navigation to Vim style?

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know of any plugins or some way to get eclipse editor navigation to mimic Vim? I've seen similar options to do this on intellij for emacs, but not Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few plug-ins available for Eclipse to support vim-like behavior. [Vrapper](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vrapper-vim) seems like one that is most close what you want. However, the Eclipse Marketplace has a few other items as well [tagged as vim](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/vim).